# Vertical form with transitions feat. Microsoft Edge

Tags: css, css-transitions, microsoft-edge

I am having some troubles with Microsoft Edge and CSS while working on a step-by-step form with vertical transitions.
All of the steps have a `position: absolute` property. The parent container (the one that contains the steps) has a `position: relative` property.

The current step is displayed in the middle of the screen. 
Each next step of the form, which then "pushes" to the top the current step to take its place, is hidden past the bottom of the page with a `bottom: -100%`. 
The previous step then has `top: -100%` to go and hide past the top of the page.

In Microsoft Edge, the first two steps work pretty well. Then when reaching the third step, suddenly the `bottom: -100%` starts acting as if it was a `bottom: 0px`, which results in having all of my steps stacked up at the bottom of the screen, all displayed, leaving the form ugly and unusable.

Needless to say that I don't have the problem in Chrome nor Firefox. Is there maybe something special that I should know about how Edge handles elements with a `position: absolute` tag ?

Here is a drawing of what's working perfectly well in other browsers:
[image: drawing]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use something else than percent, maybe :

```
Top: 100vh;
```